# Cannot estimate size of Kafka JSON message

Tags: python, json, unix, apache-kafka

I need to send the JSON message by Kafka but my application has a limit for size of messages.

The message will be built by Python script. The script will read base JSON from file, transform it and write it to file. Therefore I need to estimate the size of created JSON.

And the main problem is that when I load the file to python script and I try to check size (in bytes) of this json by calling `sys.getsizeof(json)` I get `240`. And when I check the size of file using shell tools by calling `stat -f%z stack.json` or `cat stack.json | wc -c` I get `206`. (I use macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3).

And the most important question is how Kafka interprets the message size? This will be 206, 240 or maybe other value?

My JSON (without white spaces):

`{"metadata":{"info":"important info"},"timestamp":"2018-04-06T12:19:38.611Z","content":{"id":"1","name":"name test","objects":[{"id":"1","url":"http://example.com","properties":[{"id":"1","value":"1"}]}]}}`

Python script:

```
import json
import sys


def get_contents_from_json(file_path)-> dict:
    try:
        with open(file_path) as file:
            contents = file.read()
            return json.loads(contents)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Error while reading json file')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The JSON file was not found at the given path: \n{file_path}')

STACK_JSON = 'stack.json';


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_contents_from_json(STACK_JSON)
    size_of_json = sys.getsizeof(data)
    print(size_of_json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your example and got totally different result.

First, I copied your given json string. And use `len(json_str)`, get its length as `205`. And I save it as a text file `json_str.json`, and get its size as `205B`. That makes sense.

Second, I use `sys.getsizeof(json_str)` to get its memory size and get `254`, that also makes sense as an empty sting in python3 has `49` size. Add `205` and equal to `254`.

So I really cannot understand the results you given in question.

Comment: Ok, I read json as dict object and when I created string from this dict I've got size 273 and length 224. But when I paste this string directly to script and I've got length 206 and size 206. So can I guess that Kafka determine size of json to 206 bytes?

Comment: If you want to transport a json object, you actually transport it as a json-format string. So the way you calculate message's size should be calculating the size of that string and minus the size of empty string in python which is `49` in python3. So the transported message's size of the given example should be `205B`(On my computer, it seems `206B` on your computer.)